# How to stop Maven Clean failing due to an undeletable file?

Tags: maven

I attempt: mvn clean

and receive an error about this file that couldn't be cleaned up.

Error received:

```
Failed to delete C:\Users\user\Desktop\thymeleafexamples-stsm-3.0-master\target\tomcat\logs\access_log.2019-06-17
```

Comment: The problem is on your machine..The system does not allow to delete the given file...which usually means it's being used by other process...(Usual windows issues)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Tomcat is still running (in the background) and stops you from deleting the file.

Comment: Yes! For some reason XAMPP picked up on the running process and it appeared as if XAMPP was already running tomcat...but it wasnt... I don't know how that works.